# Perform calculation of innerHTML number input

Tags: javascript, html, function

At the moment, I display the amount of characters which are typed into a text box.

I wish to use an alternative display option and show the estimated duration. This means the inputted character amount needs dividing by 15 to give an estimated time (there is roughly 15 characters to 1 second of speech)

How can I add a math calculation to the function below?

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('inputTXT');
inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    boxInput = e.target.value;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = boxInput.length;
});
```

[image]

Comment: i dont see any math dividing by fifteen in here

Comment: Did you try `boxInput.length / 15`?

Comment: Yep, just comes back as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra element and use that element to calculate the result of dividing the number of characters from the input with the length method and then dividing by 15. Note I use Math.round() to round the numbers.

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('inputTXT');

    inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        boxInput = e.target.value;
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = boxInput.length;
        document.getElementById('duration').innerHTML = Math.round(boxInput.length/15);

});
```

```html
 <form>
      <input type="text" id="inputTXT" name="firstname">
      <div>
      <label>characters: <label id="number">0</label></label>
      </div>
      <div>
      <label>duration: <label id="duration">0</label></label>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: HI @bruno-li try to learn how to use stackoverflow snippets usage avoid external link snippets

Comment: Will do, thanks for letting me know. I have just signed up and learning how to use the website.